# SourceTree not staging directories/subdirectories

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been working on a project and wanted to push it to my Github repository for the first time. I cloned the repo to a folder on my Desktop, and it had the README file.

I copied my solution into the folder, but when I went to Sourcetree there were no new files/folders to stage.

The directory looked like

```
Project1
 MainSolutionDir
 otherfiles
```

I took the files/folders from under Project1 and put them straight into the main folder, and I was able to commit the files and delete them, but after each commit the MainSolutionDir was not staged/pushed.

How do I enable SourceTree to stage directories?

Comment: What does `git status` give you?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not using a shell at the time and am now at work, so I am not sure what it would have said.

Comment: @Peaceful it looks like my program folder is read only, not sure if that would make a difference for source control?

Comment: But still try using `git status`. My hunch is that you didn't use `git add` before committing.

Comment: have you found the solution?